# PHP string replace modifiers

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I am trying to write some string replace functions, and rather than ask how to do a specific replace, I want to know more about modifiers so I can do it myself

Take this for example:

```
preg_replace('~[\W\s]~', ' ', $input);
```

or

```
strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $s));
```

What are those called? (~[\W\s]~) (![^A-Z]+!)
They make very little sense to read or make up a new one.  Where can I find all of them?  Or learn how to write them?

Comment: Those are called **regular expressions**

Comment: they're called regular expressions. They are extremely powerful, though a bit daunting at first. [This is a good site to learn more about them](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Note PHP uses PCRE regex's (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called Regular Expressions. From http://www.regular-expressions.info , 'A regular expression (regex or regexp for short) is a special text string for describing a search pattern. You can think of regular expressions as wildcards on steroids.'

Here is a site with references and a playground to test working with them.

http://regexr.com